# Can rendering of a big Pageblocktable lead to CPU timeout errors?

Tags: pageblocktable, custom-controller, cpulimit

In my page after clicking a custom save button I am rerendering a huge `apex:pageBlockTable` with 150+ rows, 20 columns.

```
    <apex:repeat value="{!fields}" var="field">

        <apex:column > 
            <apex:inputField value="{!row.record[field]}" rendered="{!isEditable[field.FieldPath] == true}" required="{!field.DbRequired || field.Required}" />

        </apex:column>
    </apex:repeat>

</apex:pageBlockTable>
```

This leads to a `CPU timeout error`. When I check the logs I see the getter of `rows` called over and over again.

I would not expect the getter to be called more than once. Why is that? And could this be the reason?

Comment: How many records are you looping over?

Comment: 150+ records. In my DE org it even worked for 300+, but in the customer org much more custom code (triggers, validation rules, worflows) run. They all consume CPU time.

Comment: You could time out, especially with an input in every cell, but I think `View State` will be a more pertinent constraint. Your component tree is going to be **heavy**. In terms of CPU time, it might help to calculate all the rendered logic on the back end and just remove those fields from your collection.

Comment: @AdrianLarson what do you mean by "it might help to calculate all the rendered logic on the back end and just remove those fields from your collection"?

Comment: Oh sorry I kind of merged the `rendered` and `required` criteria in my head. That won't help.