# Leverage StandardSetController pagination in Edit grid

Tags: visualforce, custom-controller, pagination, standardsetcontroller, cpulimit

There are numerous examples out there how to use `StandardSetController` to display Table grids for many SObject records. It's internal pagination mechanism is very helpful to e.g. reduce Viewstate on a Visualforce page that would without pagination display too many fields.

I could no find a single example of using `StandardSetController` and pagination in such a table where each row (=SObject) uses apex:inputField instead of apex:outputFields and has a Save option.

But that is exactely what I need. Until now I displayed and saved hundreds of record on a single VF page and ran into [CPU time limits](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/69576/can-rendering-of-a-big-pageblocktable-lead-to-cpu-timeout-errors) in customer orgs where many formula fields, validation and workflow rules where defined on the rows SObject.

**Did you build something like this and want to share some experiences or did you see that on the web (tutorial, Github repo,...)?**